# English translation of Helmholtz' paper: “On the Physical Significance of the Principle of Least Action”

Tags: specific-reference, history, variational-principle

I am asking about an English translation of a Helmholtz paper:

> Ueber die physikalische Bedeutung des Princips der kleinsten Wirkung. *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (Crelle's Journal), Volume 100, Issue 2, 1887, Pages 137-166, and Volume 100, Issue 3, 1887, Pages 213-222.*

http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1887.issue-100/crll.1887.100.137/crll.1887.100.137.xml?format=INT. (Also see [link](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl/?GDZPPN002160013) and [link](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl/?GDZPPN002160072).)

The title in English: *On the Physical Significance of the Principle of Least Action.*

Has it ever been translated (to English)?

Comment: I just took a quick look at the paper, and the notation is funny - the same letters are used, but with different meanings: the coordinates are $p$ instead of $q$, which in turn is used for the velocities $\dot q$; momenta are $c$ instead of $p$, potentials are $F$ instead of $V$, the Lagrangian is called $H$ and has the opposite sign, ie corresponds to $-L$; kinetic energy is called $L$ instead of $T$; the Hamiltonian is called $H'$ instead of $H$

Comment: Hi @Gugg. I think the German spelling mistakes (when compared to modern German) in the original German title will generate an endless edit war. Perhaps one should display _both_ the original _and_ a grammatically correct German title? (Also note that Helmholtz spells 'Prinicips' with 3 i's!)

Comment: @Qmechanic Hmmm,... NO. :) I think there are no spelling mistakes in the original title. At the time, they were using both Ue's as well as u-umlauts (see the paper itself), but apparently only Ue's in titles. Also "Princips" had been converted to modern-day German (although my German is lousy). The current version proved to be much more useful in Internet search. That is, the misspelling/modernization made it more time-consuming. Also, I don't expect an edit war. Almost certainly, I won't participate.

Comment: @Qmechanic To your edited comment. The 3 i's: Not in the title, he doesn't. Does he?

Comment: @Glen The Udderboat: Ups, you're right. That's just a typo of the website.

Comment: I am used to Einstein's original papers, and that "Princips" with C is hurting my eyes... Germans have had some (from my point of view) horrible spelling reforms. I believe at least two in the last decades, but I am not sure.

Comment: I've no access from home to the two last links you send. But you clearly asked for *two* different papers, didn't you ?

Comment: @Oaoa A. I included those links in the question because they are _free_, but they may need a further click, or [link1](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002160013) and [link2](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002160072). B. The second part is "a _continuation_ of the article in this volume page 137."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this thread's ancient, but I had the exact same question and it looks like there's currently an English translation of this paper by D. H. Delphenic available here:

http://neo-classical-physics.info/uploads/3/0/6/5/3065888/helmholtz_-_physical_meaning_of_least_action.pdf

Archived here in case the link expires:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210506142203/neo-classical-physics.info/uploads/3/0/6/5/3065888/helmholtz_-_physical_meaning_of_least_action.pdf

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 6):

In English, I've only found this very limited translation by [Yourgrau and Mandelstam](http://books.google.com/books/about/Variational_principles_in_dynamics_and_q.html?id=OwTyrJJXZbYC).

> From these facts we may even now draw the conclusion that the
>   domain of validity of the principle of least action has reached far beyond the
>   boundaries of the mechanics of ponderable bodies. Maupertuis’ high hopes for
>   the absolute general validity of his principle appear to be approaching their
>   fulfilment, however slender the mechanical proofs and however contradictory the
>   metaphysical speculations which the author himself could at the time adduce in
>   support of his new principle. Even at this stage, it can be considered as highly
>   probable that it is the universal law pertaining to all processes in nature. . . . In
>   any case, the general validity of the principle of least action seems to me
>   assured, since it may claim a higher place as a heuristic and guiding principle in
>   our endeavour to formulate the laws governing new classes of phenomena.

---

Perhaps useful for other readers is the full Russian translation in Полак, Л.С. (ред.), *Вариационные принципы механики: Сборник статей классиков науки*, 1959. There's a djvu file [here](http://en.books4study.org/ebook2130.html). The file can be converted to pdf at, e.g., http://www.djvu-pdf.com/. The Russian-translated paper is at page 430ff (pdf-page 434ff).

Answer (score -1):

In the book ["Intellectual Mastery of Nature. Theoretical Physics from Ohm to Einstein, Volume 2: The Now Mighty Theoretical Physics, 1870 to 1925"](https://books.google.de/books?id=7eggQO_Eey4C) you can find, on pages 131-134 some parts are translated.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really loved here. The main problem is with them that the remote links can die. I would suggest to duplicate its essential content into your answer.